# Generate a new numpy array of order 2 filling in each element with a random number in a certain range

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy. What's the best way to create a new array and fill each element with a random number within a certain range?

For example I want a *3-by-3* array where each element is either a `0` or a `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like

```
np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 3))
```

See [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) documentation for further details.

---

For example:

```
import numpy as np
print np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```